# Jquery Mobile dynamic created range change event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a Jquery Mobile range dynamic with this code:

```
$('<input data-type="' + elementType + '" id="' + name +' " min=' + value1 +' max=' + value2 + ' value="127" >').appendTo("fieldset");
```

Now I want to add a change event with this code:

```
$(".brightness").change(function() {
        alert("changed");
});
```

I have no idea why it's not working, I tried to refresh the range after defining the event, I tried to bind the event to the range, nothing works. The function that contains the first code snippet, is getting called first, and the function that contains the second snipped is getting called second.

Does someone of you know what I'm doing wrong, or what I'm overlooking?

Comment: Are you trying to add the change event to that element you just added ? Because I see no `brightness` class in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to do
1. add css class `brightness` to your range input

```
$('<input class="brightness" data-type="' + elementType + '" id="' + name +' " min=' + value1 +' max=' + value2 + ' value="127" >').appendTo("fieldset");
```

2. Add event handler using `on`

`$(document).on("change",".brightness",function() {
       alert("changed");
 });`

**EDIT** - for id selector use `#` instead of `.`(dot) like below 
`$(document).on("change","#brightness",function() {
       alert("changed");
 });`

Check **[jQuery Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)**

Comment: Ah, when i set the class, it ist working, thank you, but why? The id (in the name variable) is brightness too, why isn't it working with the id?

Comment: for using id, put `#` instead of `.` (dot) like `#brightness` because # is used as id selector and dot for class selector in jquery. And for dynamically added elements, use `on` for binding event handler

Answer (score 0):

Use on method for your dynamically created elements

```
$(".brightness").on('change',function() {
        alert("changed");
});
```

Comment: When I set the class, like in Bhushan Kawadkar's example it is working, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are giving id brightness and Calling  Onchange Event by Class using dot(.).

if the name of the id is brightness then 
you should use #

```
 $("#brightness").on('change',function() {
        alert("changed");
});
```

but if you want call `onchange` event by class only then you need to add class to your input and use dot(.)

```
$('<input class="brightness" data-type="' + elementType + '" id="' + name +' " min=' + value1 +' max=' + value2 + ' value="127" >').appendTo("fieldset");

$(".brightness").on('change',function() {
    alert("changed");
});
```